# UILocalNotification triggering multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am using UILocalNotification and here's my code

```
-(void)notificationScheduler
{
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
   // localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:7];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"NPS message";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotification.repeatInterval = 0;
    //Setting badge
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

I am calling this method in a button click action. Notification is delivering to phone continuously.

I tried this code to stop the notification

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveLocalNotification");
    [application cancelLocalNotification:notification];

}
```

but `didReceiveLocalNotification` method is not getting called.

Button action code

```
- (IBAction)btnSendClicked:(id)sender
{

    [self notificationScheduler ];

    // saves in dB of sttarter and then reloads tableview to display the message.

    if (![self.txtMessage.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        // publish message
        [objSttarter SttarterClassPublishTopic:strTopicIdToCompare strData:self.txtMessage.text];

        NSMutableDictionary *dctMessage = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dctMessage setValue:@"message" forKey:@"type"];
        [dctMessage setValue:@"" forKey:@"timestamp"];
        [dctMessage setValue:@"You" forKey:@"from"];
        [dctMessage setValue:@"none" forKey:@"file_type"];
        [dctMessage setValue:@"" forKey:@"file_url"];
        [dctMessage setValue:@"False" forKey:@"sender"];// false = You sent a msg back.

        NSMutableDictionary *dctPayload =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dctPayload setValue:@"" forKey:@"title"];
        [dctPayload setValue:strTopicIdToCompare forKey:@"topic"];//*
        [dctPayload setValue:self.txtMessage.text forKey:@"message"];//*
        [dctMessage setValue:dctPayload forKey:@"payload"];

        [[DatabaseHandler sharedDatabaseHandler] insertDataToMessages:dctMessage];

//        NSIndexPath *path1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:arrmsg.count inSection:0];
//        NSArray *indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:path1,nil];
//        [arrmsg addObject:self.txtMessage.text];
//        [self.tableviewChat beginUpdates];
//        [self.tableviewChat insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
//        [self.tableviewChat endUpdates];
//        [self.view endEditing:YES];
//        self.txtMessage.text=@"";

     self.txtMessage.text =@"";

    }
}
```

Comment: I take it that this `IBAction` is triggered by the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event?

Comment: yes, UIControlEventTouchUpInside only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed appdelegate didReceiveLocalNotification code to this and it worked.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveLocalNotification");
    [application cancelLocalNotification:notification];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];


}
```

Comment: This is a work around, but not the solution. You shouldn't need to cancel the other notifications. Can you show us the code where you trigger the notification? e.g. the button press code.

Comment: @siburb I have added button action code in Question.